# Get EVP_PKEY from EVP_PKEY_CTX

Tags: c++, c, openssl, libcrypto

I have a function that takes as parameter an EVP_PKEY_CTX*. I cannot modify the function signature in any way. Is there any way to get the EVP_PKEY object from the EVP_PKEY_CTX ?

My code would look something like this :

```
void foo(EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx) {
    EVP_PKEY *pkey;
    pkey = ctx->pkey // This does not work but it is essentially what I want to do
    // Do operations with pkey
    bar(pkey);
}
```

Comment: Does `EVP_PKEY_CTX_get0_pkey` somehow not work for you ?

Comment: No it works fine and this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. It does not appear to be documented anywhere in [openssl documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/) that is why I could find it.

Comment: That's super odd. I concur, I cannot see it either. I'd say "Use the Source, Luke", but I'm certain there is a reason for that omission. Sometimes Matt Caswell pops in on the openssl topic. He may have more information on that if he sees this. Or perhaps ask on their wiki.

Comment: It's just an omission from the man page because no one contributed the docs for it yet. This is the right function to use. Pull Request welcome to add the missing documentation!